# Chat via WIFI platform independent

Tags: android, p2p, alljoyn

I'm thinking of creating a chat app which is similar like firechat. which needs no internet for communication and depends only on BT or WIFI to communicate and also have an advantage of platform independent. 
      I've seen many sites referring some sites like open garden for firechat and alljoyn framework. I really don't understand what this things are for. Its really hard to find a solution for this.

I tried alljoyn initially, but the last update was about 3 years ago. the sample apps crashes in devices. 
      So any one who worked in this kinda project or or sharing some knowledge will be more helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The official website is outdated, use git repo (git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/core/alljoyn.git), a chat is one of the samples.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a well-known chat sample in AllJoyn Core, which discovers other peers and connect them. It works on Android App too.

Here you can download the AllJoyn Android Chat sample https://cgit.allseenalliance.org/core/alljoyn.git/tree/alljoyn_java/samples/android/chat

Comment: But there is no recent updates or commits in this! It has been active on 2014 its 2017 there has been several changes ocurred between this past three years!

Comment: Did you check the logs, https://cgit.allseenalliance.org/core/alljoyn.git/log/alljoyn_java/samples/android/chat it seems new. The framework changed a lot, but I guess the chat sample deserves a try.